# Ruby on rails. Devise registrations edit - user attributes not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have added extra pages to the registrations controller to clean up the user account settings page. My issue is that on these new pages, although I can update the user's attributes, these attributes are not shown in the views.
I am referring to the fact that the previously saved attribute should be shown in it's corresponding input on the form.

The form attributes that I've left on the `users/edit` page do show the saved attributes, but the new pages don't.

I have added new pages as follows;

Routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions" }
  devise_scope :user do
  get "/users/account", to: "users/registrations#account"
  get "/users/media", to: "users/registrations#media"
  get "/users/notifications", to: "users/registrations#notifications"
  end
```

Users/registrations controller;

```
   def account
     build_resource({})
     respond_with self.resource
   end

   def media
     build_resource({})
     respond_with self.resource
   end

   def notifications
     build_resource({})
     respond_with self.resource
   end
```

Form on each page:

```
`<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %`>
```

Why aren't the saved attributes showing on these new pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have figured it out.

Instead of using:

```
build_resource({})
respond_with self.resource
```

I have added

```
    def account
         @user = current_user
         if @user
           render :account
         else
           redirect_to root_url
         end
       end

........etc.....
```

Now the attributes are showing correctly.